# Every GA pageview and event creating a new user

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am doing custom pageviews in my code like this:

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'custom page name']);

trouble is, each time I do this GA is tracking a new user for some reason.  I'm using this to track usage of a single page.  They are doing several things on the page and for each action I push a unique pageview. So if the user does three things on the page, I wind up with three new users who each went straight to that action.  So it's useless.

I also tried tracking these things as events....same result.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Installed a GA debugger on Chrome and each push definitely resets the visitor id.  how do i stop it from doing that??

Comment: do you have your browser set to not accept cookies or are you wiping your cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

We were hardcoding the domain name like this:
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName',;hardcoded name]);

so any lifecycle other than the hardcoded one was resetting visitors on every pageview.